# Combine search and will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

User can do a quick search for a specific record in a database. I also added a will paginate, but when I did, the search bar didn't work. How can I fix this?

my controller

```
class VendorsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @vendors = Vendor.search(params[:search])

        @vendors = Vendor.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)

    end

#...
end
```

index

```
#...
<table>
    <tr>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>    
            <%= button_to "New Vendor", new_vendor_path, :method => "get" %>
        <% end %>
        <%= button_to "Inventory", inventories_path, :method => "get" %>
        <%= form_tag vendors_path, :method => "get" do %>
            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
            <%= submit_tag "Search", :contact_name => nil %>
        <% end %>
        <div class = "pag" >
            <%= will_paginate @vendors %>
        </div>            
    </tr>
</table>
#...
```

Comment: Define please - _search bar didn't work_. Also read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

In the index you are replacing the value of @vendors from the search results, with the value from the paginate results.

```
class VendorsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @vendors = Vendor.search(params[:search])

        @vendors = Vendor.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)

    end

#...
end
```

Try this to paginate the search results...

```
class VendorsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @vendors = Vendor.search(params[:search]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)

    end

#...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're assigning the value of `@venders` twice in your Index action, with the second one always overriding the first.